# EXCEL: SUMIFS criterion applied to a INDEX MATCH search equals a value

Tags: excel, indexing, match, sumifs

I've spent pretty much all day trying to figure this out. I've read so many threads on here and on various other sites. This is what I'm trying to do:

I've got the total sales output. It's large and the number of items on it varies depending on the time frame it's looked at. There is a major lack in the system where I cannot get the figures by region. That information is not stored in the system. The records only store the customer's name, the product information, number of units, price, and purchase date. I want to get the total number of each item sold by region so that I can compare item popularity across regions.

There are only about 50 customers, so it is feasible for me to create a separate sheet assigning a region to the customers.

So, I have three sheets:
Sheet 1: Sales

```
+-----------------------------------------------------+
|Customer Name | Product | Amount | Price |   Date    |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Joe's Fish   | RT-01   |      7 |  5.45 | 2020/5/20 |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Joe's Fish   | CB-23   |     17 |  0.55 | 2020/5/20 |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Mack's Bugs  | RT-01   |      4 |  4.45 | 2020/4/20 |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Joe's Fish   | VX-28   |      1 |  1.20 | 2020/5/13 |
-------------------------------------------------------
| Karen's \/   | RT-01   |      9 |  3.45 | 2020/3/20 |
+-----------------------------------------------------+
```

Sheet 2: Regions

```
+----------------------+
|  Customer   | Region |
------------------------
| Joe's Fish  |     NA |
------------------------
| Mack's Bugs |     NA |
------------------------
| Karen's \/  |     EU |
+----------------------+
```

And my results are going in Sheet 3:

```
+----------------------+
|       |   NA |    EU |
------------------------
| RT-01 |   11 |     9 |
+----------------------+
```

So looking at the data I made up for this question, I want to compare the number of RW-01's sold in North America to those sold in Europe. I can do it if I add an INDEX MATCH column to the end of the sales sheet, but I would have to do that every time I update the sales information. 
Is there some way to do a SUMIFS like:

```
SUMIFS(Sheet1!$D:$D,Sheet1!$A:$A,INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(Sheet1!#Current A#,Sheet2!$A:$A))=Sheet3!$B2,Sheet1!$B:$B,Sheet3!$A3)
```

?

Comment: Why not use a VLOOKUP to add the region to the table on sheet1 and then you can just use SUMIFS.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's difficult to do it with a SUMIFS because the columns you're matching have to be ranges, but you can certainly do it with a SUMPRODUCT and COUNTIFS:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10=$A2)*COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5,B$1))
```

[image]

I don't recommend using full-column references because it could be slow.

BTW I was assuming that there were no duplicates in Sheet2 for a particular combination of customer and region - if there were, you could use

```
=SUMPRODUCT(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$10*(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$10=$A2)*
(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$5,Sheet1!$A$2:$A$10,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$5,B$1)>0))
```

**EDIT**

It is worth using a dynamic version of the formula, though it is not elegant:

```
=SUM(Sheet1!$C2:INDEX(Sheet1!$C:$C,MATCH(2,1/(Sheet1!$C:$C<>"")))*(Sheet1!$B2:INDEX(Sheet1!$B:$B,MATCH(2,1/(Sheet1!$B:$B<>"")))=$A2)*
(COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$A:$A,MATCH(2,1/(Sheet2!$A:$A<>""))),Sheet1!$A2:INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MATCH(2,1/(Sheet1!$A:$A<>""))),Sheet2!$B$2:INDEX(Sheet2!$B:$B,MATCH(2,1/(Sheet2!$B:$B<>""))),B$1)>0))
```

Comment: Thank you! I'll give this a shot today and let you know how it works for me.

Comment: It worked perfectly, thank you. I understand the warning about full column reference, but unless there is a way (non-vba, don't have time to learn it now) to have it detect the last row, I have to take the hit as I want this to be plug and play. Sometimes there will be several hundred rows, or like what I'm using now several hundred thousand. I need it made in a way where the technologically illiterate can download the system's CVS, and copy it into the "sales" sheet, then get the info. Thank you again for the tremendous help.

Comment: Could try a standard way of getting the last row like =MATCH(2,1/(A:A<>"")) . I'm not sure how much faster it would make it than full-column references without setting up a test. I have to do other stuff right now, but will come back to it later.

Comment: Well I have done a test and the bad news is that it doesn't work with full-column references for both Sheet1 and Sheet2. It is worth making the formula dynamic though. I imagine the number of customers in sheet 2 won't be nearly as much as the number of products though, so it would work with a large number of products using a formula like the one in my answer. It would be more elegant to use a named range, but from my experience it isn't a good idea to send out sheets with named ranges in them.

Comment: It works if you skip the headers. Instead of A:A do A2:A and it works fine for me. The problem I've run into now is I got greedy and wanted to  compare series (RT-* vs CW-*), but SUMPRODUCT doesn't like that.

Answer (score 0):

As you would need to make the match in memory I don't think it's feasible in Excel, you'll have to use a vba dictionary.
On the other hand, if the number of columns is fixed in your sales sheet, you can just format as table and add your index match in F.
When updating the sales data delete all lines as of line 3 and copy paste the update value. Excel will automatically apply the index match on all rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said in a comment to Tom Sharpe, I don't have the time to learn VBA right now. His answer worked well. Maybe in the future when I'm not under a deadline for this and I can sit and learn VBA, I'll come back and review your kind answer.